# Download maps offline with Google Maps v8

Tags: google-maps, offline-map

With the latest version of Google Maps (v8.1.0) I am trying to download offline maps from Spain, but I am having no success.

This was doable in previous version in a simple way, but I can not find a solution with the latest version.

Can someone lead me to the way to achieving this?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91821/some-contact-pictures-wont-sync-with-facebook-contact-pictures-on-htc-one-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps) application.

Select an area you want to save the map for. Once the red pin appears you will have the street name at the bottom of the screen and the 'route' icon.

Swipe this white box upwards.

One of the options is `Save map to use offline`

Comment: It doesnt seem to work in Spain. How come?

Comment: It works fine for me here for areas in Spain, I just tried three cities with no issue. You have to hold your finger on the area you want, then click on the red pin that appears. There's a white box at the bottom that has the street name, drag that up and then the option is in there with Street View, Reviews, Pictures etc...

Comment: I get "Area unavailable". What cities have you succesfully downloaded? Are there country restrictions, depending on my carrier?

Comment: How bizarre, you're right. It worked on the border with Portugal for a few towns but most of Spain is unavailable... That's very odd. Apparently Google has obtained the map data for Spain from the Insituto Geográfico Nacional (IGN) and I am guessing that the licensing agreement prevents them from offering for offline use, like when the data was obtained from TeleAtlas.

Comment: That is weird because in previous versions I could download it... Anyway. The question itself is answered, even if it does not help me. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry there's not more on it, I'll check tomorrow and see if there's something more concrete or a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

To download maps offline in Google Maps 7 & 8, adjust specific area of maps you wanna save offline on your screen and then type "ok maps" in the search box and press enter.